# ffmpeg: How to fix `Unsupported channel layout "1 channels (FL)" error`, when I convert the source containing separated FL/FR audio streams?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

### Problem

I want to convert the MOV file containing the separated FL/FR audio streams to MP4 file, transcoding the video to h264 and the audio to AAC.
However, it fails with the following error:

`[aac @ 0x7ff515000c00] Unsupported channel layout "1 channels (FL)"`

The source video and command what I used is as the following section.

### How To Reproduce

Download `ticket1474.mov` as the source from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1474, 
this source contains the following streams:
(The streams in issue are #0:1 and #0:2)

```
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main) (xdvf / 0x66766478), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 34801 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-06-19T21:18:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : XDCAM EX 1080p30 (35 Mb/s VBR)
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-06-19T21:18:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s16, 768 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-06-19T21:18:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-06-19T21:18:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      reel_name       : Untitled
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
```

Then run the following command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ticket1474.mov -b:a 128k -map 0 -y sample.mp4
```

You'll get the following error:

```
(snip)

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)

(snip)

[aac @ 0x7ffbd203e400] Unsupported channel layout "1 channels (FL)"
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

### ffmpeg Version

```
$ ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version N-93875-gc2771bbf81-tessus
```

Note: Stable version (ffmpeg-4.2) also fails.

### What I Tried (Converting FL/FR streams to dual mono channel)

I guessed the problem can be solved if I could convert FL/FR streams to dual mono streams.

But I couldn't find the appropriate usage of ffmpeg for such scene.

The command I have tried is the following which also failed:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ticket1474.mov -b:a 128k -filter_complex '[0:1]pan=mono|FC=FL[mono];[0:2]pan=mono|FC=FR[mono]' -y sample.mp4

(snip)

Filter pan has an unconnected output
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use pan filter, you can reassign channel layout using the channelmap filter.

```
ffmpeg -i ticket1474.mov -af channelmap=0 -b:a 128k -map 0:v -map 0:a -y sample.mp4
```

See [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap) for channelmap filter.

I've skipped mapping the timecode track. ffmpeg will set it as metadata in the input file, and the MP4 muxer will pick it up from there.